# How to handle the key press event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to handle the key press event in javascript, after user press a key on keyboard, it will print the pressed key on screen. I know I need to handle the onkeydown event, but how to do that in detail?

Comment: I am sure, there are lots of examples regarding this event. Have you done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do this job, using jQuery will make your program run well in different browsers.

```
$(function(){
  $(document).keypress(function(event){
    console.log(event.which);
  });
})
```

Above code uses **keypress** function to handle key press event, and print the pressed key's key code to your browser console

Comment: That's jQuery. The OP says they want to do this in javascript. I don't think you can expect the OP to include jQuery just for handling keypresses.